# Way of fast iterating through list

Tags: list, date, dictionary, groovy

I have a question about iterating through lists.

Let's say i have list of maps with format

```
def listOfMaps = [ ["date":"2013/05/23", "id":"1"],
                   ["date":"2013.05.23", "id":"2"],
                   ["date":"2013-05-23", "id":"3"],
                   ["date":"23/05/2013", "id":"4"] ]
```

Now i have a list of two patterns (in reality i have a lot more :D)

```
def patterns = [
     /\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/,             //'yyyy/MM/dd'
     /\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/             //'yyyy-MM-dd'
]
```

I want to println dates only with the "yyyy/MM/dd" and "yyyy-MM-dd" format so i have to go through the lists

```
for (int i = 0; i < patterns.size(); i++) {
      def findDates = listOfMaps.findAll{it.get("word") ==~ patterns[i] ? 
      dateList << it : "Nothing found"}
}
```

but i have a problem with this way. What if the list "listOfMaps" gonna be huge? It will take a lot of time to find all patters because this code will have to go through the whole list of patters and the same amount of time it will have to go through list of maps wich in case of huge lists might take a long while :). I tried with forEach inside the findAll clousure it does not work.

So my question is is there any way to go through the list of patterns inside the findAll clousure? For instance sth like this in pseudocode

```
def findDates =  listOfMaps.findAll{it.get("word") ==~ for(){patterns[i]} ?  : }
```

so in that case it goes only once through the listOfMaps list and it iterates through patterns(which always is way way way way smaller than listOfMaps).

I might have an idea to create a function that returns the instance of list, but i'm struggling to implement this :).

Thanks in advance for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
def listOfMaps = [ [date:"2013/05/23", id:"1"],
                   [date:"2013.05.23", id:"2"],
                   [date:"2013-05-23", id:"3"],
                   [date:"23/05/2013", id:"4"] ]

def patterns = [
     /\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/,             //'yyyy/MM/dd'
     /\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/             //'yyyy-MM-dd'
]

def foundRecords = listOfMaps.findAll { m ->
    patterns.find { p ->
        m.date ==~ p
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i have multiple statements in the clousure, for instance if i want to check id at the same time?

Comment: Can you make the question resemble what you mean?

Comment: if i want to check

findAll{it.get("word") == ~pattern && it.get("id") == "1" ?  : }

i had multiple if statements in mind :D

Comment: how about: `listOfMaps.findAll { m -> m.id == '1' && patterns.find { p -> m.date ==~ p } }`

Comment: it is better but as u saw im adding stuff to dateList can i use it like this {listOfMaps.findAll {m -> m.id == '1' && patterns.find{ p -> m.date ==~ p} ? dateList << m : "nothing"} } ...also i have a question how can i do multiple instructions after ? in clousure? for instance i need to add item to dateList  and for instance, println sth like {findAll{ bla bla ? dateList << m; println "we addes sth"; : "nothing was added} } but it does not work with the ";" it throws errors. Well i ask this last question because in stuff i did read about groovy there is no info about this.

Comment: You mean: `def dateList = listOfMaps.inject( [] ) { l, m -> l << ( m.id == '1' && patterns.find{ p -> m.date ==~ p} ? m : "nothing" ) }`?

Comment: No i have def dateList = collect{[:]} and i need to add all found dates in this format to that list. As u saw in my code when after "?" there is dateList << it

Comment: But you can't add multiple things with the same key to a map

Comment: Maybe a new question explaining the problems you've now got?

Comment: problem is still the same. Let me explain. I need to write a script that will show all dates from listOfMaps in a given format. So i create an empty list that will store dates that this script will find and it is def dateList = collect{[:]}. So i created the list of patterns as u sow in my first post. Then i go through loop that iterates through patterns and inside the for loop i use this function findAll. So if in that function this statement it.get("date") ==~ pattern[i] is true i need to add this found date into previously created empty list, so it is dateList << it.

Comment: Why not put this in the question?  Rather than posting a question which does not explain fully your problem, and contains code that cannot compile without editing and guessing missing variables?

Comment: I explained what i want to achieve...nvm i will find out myself how to solve this, thanks for help.

Comment: You make no mention of an `id` requirement (comment #3). Your map definition wasn't valid groovy code (edited by me). You use a variable  `dateList` which you never explain it's type, nor what you'd expect it to contain. Other than that, it's an exemplary question.